# Wicket, ajax behavior does not get register to the wicket events

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, wicket-1.6

My scenario: on an ajax event I replace a `webmarkupContainer` with one of my components which have some wicket `IBehaviorListener`.

The problem is that this replace happen due to ajax request, and the behavior get listed on dom ready:

```
Wicket.Event.add(window, "domready", function(event) { 
Wicket.Ajax.get({'u': 'some/url', 'c': 'linkId', 'e':'click'}));    
  // ... more event registrations and onDomReady scripts 
}
```

I'm assuming that, being generated in the  this event
registration
 code happens for all components that are added explicitly but not for
 any components that are added dynamically by me.

How can I call the new container with the ajax behaviors or change the current implementation so the wicket ajax behaviors would be called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do add some event registration code in your AjaxRequestTarget.

You can do this by calling

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        target.add(yourUpdatedComponents);
        ....
        target.appendJavaScript("Your registration code here");
     }
```

Comment: I want wicket to handle this registration ... by doing it my self i would b prone to bugs ....